# Access bean property to setup camel:keystore

Tags: apache-camel

I have a bean setup which returns a decoded password for a keystore. For CXF calls I can get the password using #{decoder.keystorePassword} but when I try to do the same thing from camel:keyStore password for a rest call, it doesn't work and just uses #{..} as the password. I imagine the syntax for referencing a bean is slightly different because I am in a camel component?

Any suggestions on how to get the value here?

Comment: Is decoder a bean or something you have configured as `<bean>`. Can you provide a bit more details

Comment: Its just a java file configured as <bean> with a get and set method. The set method takes an encoded password as <property> and decodes it. Then the decoded password can be accessed as above.

I have since figured out a work around where I can set a system property 'decodedPassword' in the set method and then access that property just using {{decodedPassword}} in the keystore password for CXF and rest.. does that seem like a reasonable approach? Also, I'm wondering if I can use camel:sslContextParameters for CXF or do I need to use http-conduit?